# Different Environments for AWS Media Convert?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-media-convert, amazon-cloudwatch-events

I have a use case to transcode video from one format to another format, right now jobs are running via default queue and job updates are happening from cloud-watch events to lambda triggers.

how i can split the above flow for develop, stage, production environment

1. Should i have to create separate queue for each environment?
2. Use UserMetadata attribute to differentiate environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes using multiple job queues will allow you to split the workflows. This will allow for log filtering by queue name, and controlled access to each queue.

You have additional options which can be used in any combination:

[a] Create different IAM Roles for running jobs.  This enables log filtering by role; API records for jobs submitted by Role;  and granular control of S3 access permissions.

[b] Create different AWS Accounts (which can be associated in an AWS Organization) - this will isolate all activity by account, but allow you to roll up billing and access credentials if you wish. IAM Roles can be assumed across accounts if you configure them accordingly.

[c] Programmatically add different Tags on each job which will allow filtering at the log level and billing level. Refer to the information on tagging for billing purposes here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/latest/ug/setting-up-resources-for-catt.html